# MicroPython with LCD1602 display

Tags: python, lcd, microprocessors

i have a d-series pyboard with an lcd1602 display... i am following the documentation at https://pybd.io/hw/pybd_sfxw.html, and http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/pyb.I2C.html, but i am not getting any results.

here is the code:

```
from machine import Pin
from pyb import LED
from pyb import I2C

Pin('PULL_SCL', Pin.OUT, value=1)
Pin('PULL_SDA', Pin.OUT, value=1)

lcd = I2C(1, I2C.MASTER)
print(lcd.scan())
print(lcd.is_ready(39))

lcd.send('hello', 39)
```

my terminal looks like:

```
[39]
True
```

it seems to be finding the 39 address, is appears to be ready, but nothing happens when i send text to the address.

with this code...

```
...
lcd.send(1, 39)
```

...i can turn the backlight off... no idea why that works.

any ideas on how to get text to display?

Comment: Text LCDs require a specific initialization sequence to be sent before they're even capable of displaying anything.  And depending on the specifics of the I2C interface attached to the LCD, you may not be able to send text to it directly, you may need to send 4 bits at a time.  Surely there is some sample code available for the specific LCD module you have?

Comment: ive been trying to find some... Thanks though, that makes sense.